# Middleware To Access Java Callback Interface

Tags: java, android, kotlin

First of all i am newbie at Kotlin Language and android programming.

I am trying to develop a middleware SDK to access real SDK of a POS device.
For example POS device SDK has a method like "printString()" and i am creating a method named "Print()".

People will only know the Print() method and i will access the real printString() method of device SDK.

The programming language of device SDK is Java, and my middleware SDK is Kotlin.

I actually wrote most of required methods (converted from java). But i have a one problem to create middleware of Java callback interface.

This the Java interface of device SDK

```
public interface CommonCB {
    int GetDateTime(byte[] var1);

    int ReadSN(byte[] var1);

    int GetUnknowTLV(int var1, byte[] var2, int var3);
}
```

I would like to create an interface with Kotlin named like "CommonCallback".
And people can override the above methods with calling CommonCallback class or interface.

How can i do that ? i tried many time but couldnt find a solution yet.

Comment: I don't understand what exact part you're having trouble with. Could you maybe add your attempt and why it doesn't work for you (even with hypothetical code)?

Comment: i added detailed description below, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read [ask] and its linked resources

Comment: @DoğuşEfe in your added content, you mentioned: *I want to create an interface which is inherited from CommonCB in my SDK like* - why? Why should your interface inherit from the other? You could just define your own independent interface and map callback calls from the framework to calls to your interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Java callback interface of device SDK and device library files are included to my SDK module.

```
public interface CommonCB {
    int GetDateTime(byte[] var1);

    int ReadSN(byte[] var1);

    int GetUnknowTLV(int var1, byte[] var2, int var3);
}
```

I want to create an interface which is inherited from CommonCB in my SDK like so:

```
interface CommonCallBack : CommonCB {
}
```

And third party applications will try to communicate via `CommonCallBack`

Third party app includes my module, and my SDK module includes device SDK as `.jar` file.

So when I try to access my SDK module like so:

```
var ccb = object : CommonCallBack
        {
           override fun GetDateTime(bytes: ByteArray): Int {
                val DataTimeTemp = ByteArray(10)
                return 0
            }

            override fun ReadSN(bytes: ByteArray): Int {
                var sNumber = PedApi.readPinPadSerialNumber()
                if (sNumber!=null) {
                    val nLen = (sNumber[0] - 0x30) * 10 + (sNumber[1] - 0x30) + 2
                    if (nLen > 11) ByteUtils.memcpy(
                        bytes,
                        0,
                        sNumber,
                        2 + nLen - 11,
                        11
                    ) else ByteUtils.memcpy(bytes, 0, sNumber, 2, nLen)
                }
                return CommonConstants.EmvResult.EmvOk
            }

            override fun GetUnknowTLV(i: Int, bytes: ByteArray, i1: Int): Int {
                return -1
            }
        }
```

Android Studio gives error like this:
"Cannot access 'com.****.CommonCB' which is a supertype of 'com.***.sdktestapp.sdkservice.Definitions.Companion.ccb.'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

Actually I dont want to include CommonCB library to test the application.
Is it clear now?
Thanks

Here is the basically drawing of my communication design to understand the problem better :
https://i.hizliresim.com/f2jeqep.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Updates to your question should be an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73362495/edit) to the original post along with any [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344853/295004) but realize that [images are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/295004) Answers should be for Answers to your Question, not additional info or a request for additional info.

Comment: As the above comment mentioned, please delete this answer and add the content to your question instead

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should just create your own independent interface:

```kotlin
interface CommonCallback {
    fun getDateTime(var1 ByteArray): Int

    fun readSN(var1: ByteArray): Int

    fun getUnknowTLV(var1: Int, var2: ByteArray, var3: Int): Int
}
```

(of course with proper parameter names)

Then, in your own SDK code, you can pass an original callback implementation to the original device SDK methods that need it, and that implementation would simply be an adapter that delegates all the calls to the callback provided by your users:

```kotlin
internal class CommonCBAdapter(private val cb: CommonCallback): CommonCB {
    override fun GetDateTime(bytes: ByteArray): Int = cb.getDateTime(bytes)

    override fun ReadSN(bytes: ByteArray): Int = cb.readSN(bytes)

    override fun GetUnknowTLV(i: Int, bytes: ByteArray, i1: Int): Int = cb.getUnknownTLV(i, bytes, i1)
}

// then, somewhere else still in your own code
val userCallback: CommonCallback = TODO("the user provides you with an implementation of your callback interface")

val deviceCallback = CommonCBAdapter(userCallback)

someDeviceStuff.someDeviceMethodWithCB(deviceCallback)
```